# Javascript not running on Facebook iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

I have a django project which is intended for a facebook application. In the project, the invite friends module runs fine in localhost!

[image: Runs fine on localhost]

But while it is loaded in facebook application, the javascript responsible for displaying the friends list doesn't work. Although the libraries are properly loaded.

[image: Javascript doesnot run on facebook app]

I don't know why it is so. May be some iframe problem.
**Here is the javascript code**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '460948667348013', cookie: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
           // alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
           console.log('Your name is ' + response.name);
          init();
         });
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        alert('the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated your app');
      } else {
        alert('the user is not logged in to Facebook.');
      }
     });  
}
    function init() {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          $("#username").html("<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture'/><div>" + response.name + "</div>");       
          $("#jfmfs-container").jfmfs({ 
              max_selected: 15, 
              max_selected_message: "{0} of {1} selected",
              friend_fields: "id,name,last_name",
              pre_selected_friends: [1014025367],
              exclude_friends: [1211122344, 610526078],
              sorter: function(a, b) {
                var x = a.last_name.toLowerCase();
                var y = b.last_name.toLowerCase();
                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
              }
          });
          $("#jfmfs-container").bind("jfmfs.friendload.finished", function() { 
              window.console && console.log("finished loading!"); 
          });
          $("#jfmfs-container").bind("jfmfs.selection.changed", function(e, data) { 
              window.console && console.log("changed", data);
          });                     

          $("#logged-out-status").hide();
          $("#show-friends").show();
      });
    }              

    $("#show-friends").live("click", function() {
        var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');             
        $("#selected-friends").html(friendSelector.getSelectedIds().join(', ')); 
    });                  
    function sendRequest() {
       var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');
       var sendUIDs = friendSelector.getSelectedIds().join(', '); 
       // Use FB.ui to send the Request(s)
       FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
         to: sendUIDs,
         title: 'My Great Invite',
         message: 'Check out this Awesome App!',
       }, callback);
     }
     function callback(response) {
        // alert('callback called');
       var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');
       var sendUIDs = friendSelector.getSelectedIds().join(','); 
       var uids = sendUIDs.split(',');
       var query = '';
       for(i=0;i<uids.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            query =  query + 'to[' + i + ']=' + uids[i];
        }
        else{
        query =  query + '&to[' + i + ']=' + uids[i];
        }
       }
       console.log(query);
       if(response){
        // alert('successful');
        window.location.assign("/?"+ query)
       }
       else{
        alert('failure');
       }

     }

  </script>
```

Please help ! I am stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be SSL issues.

Facebook has made many changes in few months ago.

Also you need to keep update with Facebook developer  blog.

So I am going to try to explain few things I suspected.

***App on Facebook***

1. Your **Canvas Page** should be https://apps.facebook.com/yourchoosenname

1a. Your **Canvas URL** should be https://yoursite.com/yourapplication/

**Website**

http://yoursite.com/

**Page Tab**

1. Your **Secure Canvas** should be https://yoursite.com/yourapplication/
2. Your **Page Tab URL** should be https://yoursite.com/yourapplication/
3. Your **Secure Page Tab URL** should be https://yoursite.com/yourapplication/

In this case you will need SSL Certificate for site so You can find reliable yet cheap digital certificate from [Here](https://www.thesslstore.com?aid=52910434) .

This mandatory for any Application to work on facebook.

Hope this will help you and others

Comment: My facebook app is now in sandbox mode and the canvas url only http. So, this means the script would work if the canvas url would be https?